# issues with ttorrent with android?

Tags: android, bittorrent, torrent

i was looking for a torrent library for android and came-across [ttorrent](https://github.com/mpetazzoni/ttorrent) 
.when i tried to add dependencty to gradle it gave me errors regarding slf4j-log4j12.
i ended up adding all jar files manually and managed to run the app using sample code.
But i am getting this error now.

```
ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.test.torrent-1/lib/arm64
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:431)
at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:409)
at com.test.torrent.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

i think it is trying to find a library but i cannot find it , that path does not exist in my mobile , any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-to-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: Note the `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` - you're performing network operations on the main thread. There is a _lot_ of documentation available on this topic.

Comment: but the problem is 'ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.test.torrent-1/lib/arm64'